# How do I bypass "Do you want to..." dialog after clicking script when using Unity?

Tags: unity

After I create a bash script and double click it in Unity I am prompted with this - Do you want to run "Kill Launcher", or display its contents? With Run in terminal, Dislpay, Cancel and Run as options. How can i get this window to disappear and default to Run?

Comment: @minerz029 this and that has no relationship.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be selected in Nautilus preferences on 'Behavior' tab. In 'Executable text files', you can select `Always execute`, `Always open with text editor` or `Ask each time`.

Comment: Sorry I am a bit of a Ubuntu noob, and i cant find the Nautilus preferences or the Behavior tab. I installed 12.04 and havent changed much if anything. So I am still using the Unity interface, and when I right-click on the file and select properties my only options are 'Basic', 'Permissions', 'Open With'

Comment: Launch Nautilus (the file explorer). The Preferences (or settings) window is under EDIT menu (last option I think) and the Behavior tab is one of the tabs in Preferences window.